# Why does nginx start out of turn?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

PS shows nginx as starting early on server boot.  For example, running

> ps -e -o pid,user,etime,args

shows:

> 1136 root           09:50 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
>    1147 root           09:50 cron
>    1162 root           09:50 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
>    ...
>   1248 pgb       09:43 /usr/sbin/pgbouncer -d /var/local/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
>      ...
>    1436 root           09:31 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

The third column shows elapsed run time, in minutes and seconds.

Nginx has started the same second as sshd, 7 seconds before pgbouncer, and 19 seconds before apache2.

The rc2.d scripts are:

> S20pgbouncer
>     S91apache2
>     S92nginx

So nginx *should* be starting after all the other scripts, but ps shows it to be starting first.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upstart/Init hybrids** are confusing to me but I do understand it can start things in **parallel** and that perhaps those filenames don't matter so much. Is it possible any of those were started with upstart?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto

Comment: That was it.   Removing the /etc/init/nginx.conf file eliminated the observed phenomenon.